# "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11" - What is the issue?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, compiler-errors, label

I did some research and still have no idea what is causing this error in my code (well, I know what is causing it, but I don't know why...)

Essentially, I retrieve an array, `results`, from Parse Cloud Code. Then I send it to ViewController2 to print out a section of the array in the format of a `UILabel`. When I do this I get the compiler error. This is really confusing me!

Please note that `result`, the array that I retrieve contains both Strings and Boolean values which is why I made it `AnyObject` so I could cast specific parts later.

Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("checkAccountStatus", function(request, response) {

var results = [];
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", request.params.username);
query.first({
        success: function(getUserData) {

        if (request.params.operation == 1) {

            var passwordChanged = getUserData.get("passwordChanged");
            var question1 = getUserData.get("question1");
            var question2 = getUserData.get("question2");
            var question3 = getUserData.get("question3");

            results.push(passwordChanged);
            results.push(question1);
            results.push(question2);
            results.push(question3);

        }

        else {

            if (request.params.answerToQuestion1 == getUserData.get("answer1")) {

                results.push(true)
            }

            else {

                results.push(false)
            }

            if (request.params.answerToQuestion2 == getUserData.get("answer2")) {

                results.push(true)
            }

            else {

                results.push(false)
            }

            if (request.params.answerToQuestion3 == getUserData.get("answer3")) {

                results.push(true)
            }

            else {

                results.push(false)
            }
        }

            response.success(results);

        },
        error: function(error) {

            response.error("There was an error");

        }
});
});
```

ViewController1 Code (Part of it):

```
 var data: AnyObject!

 PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("checkAccountStatus", withParameters: ["username" : self.username.text, "operation" : 1]) {
            (result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            if (error == nil) {

            self.data = result

            //...

            }
 }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "reset") {
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController2;

        svc.data = data
    }
}
```

ViewController2 Code:

```
@IBOutlet var question1: UILabel!
var data: AnyObject!

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     question1.text = data[1] as String! //THIS GIVES ME THE ERROR.
}
```

Comment: Are you using Xcode 6.3 Swift1.2?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 6.1.1

Comment: I don't know about the swift version

Comment: I am asking this because Xcode 6.3 has a lot of this errors and they were all caused by read-only computed property vars and the only work around I found was putting them inside a class or extension

Comment: Ya I'm only have a free dev account so I don't have access to 6.3. Do you know what might be he problem in my code? :)

Comment: You can also download the beta version it is available to free accounts also

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/

Comment: Oh...but aren't the betas full of glitches...not what I want!!! :p

Comment: Yeah specially this one we are talking about

Comment: Ok but I'm using 6.1.1 right now....am I running into a glitch right now or is there a solution for this specific version?

Comment: I have never had this problem using 6.1.1 BTW 6.1.1 was the most stable version I have used so far

Comment: So your saying my code should work?!?!

Comment: I am saying that when I was using 6.1.1 if it did not find any syntax error it would compile without a problem which is not the case with 6.3

Comment: So is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: like I said in Swift 1.2 Xcode 6.3 i had to move the read-only computed property vars inside any class or extension

Comment: Sorry...I'm kinda new to Swift/Xcode...I have no idea what your talking about

Comment: I will show you an example of read-only computed property

Comment: After a bit of trial and error I just found a workaround...kinda stupid because it's literally the same code put somewhere else but....it works.....

Comment: var type:String { return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("type") ?? "none" }

Comment: so if I declare it as top level read-only computed var it would give me this 11 error only with Xcode 6.3 but If I put it inside a class Load { ... } and use it like this Load().type would work

Comment: There's a chance that there are errors that the compiler is missing (happened on Xcode 7).  Try deleting and re-adding the file and cleaning to catch an syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("checkAccountStatus", withParameters: ["username" : self.username.text, "operation" : 1]) {
        (result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

to

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("checkAccountStatus", withParameters: ["username" : self.username.text, "operation" : 1]) {
        (result: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

I had the same error when using AnyObject with findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock. Seems similar to: [this link](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/280) which was caused due to changes in the Parse SDK

Comment: Incidentally it happened the other way around for me — changing

`(objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in`

to

`(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in`.

Very weird.